# Swift UIView.animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

after I updated my Xcode to the Xcode7.0, the method below raises a very strange error: 'Double' is not convertible to 'FloatLiteralConvertible'.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5 , initialSpringVelocity: 0.3, options: nil, animations: nil, completion: nil)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error doesn't seem related to the real problem here, with Swift 2.0 `options` are now `OptionSetType` and you should pass an empty `Array` if you want to specify no options. Also seems I had to specify the closure for `animations` (non-nullable).

This should work :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.3, options: [], animations: {}, completion: nil)
```